# The Jasper reports doesn't open from the java dist jar, from an other computer

Tags: java, jar

I created a java application using Netbeans 12 IDE. The application connects to a mysql database and for reports I used JasperSoftStudio 6.17. The application and the reports runs fine from my computer. Instead, when I move the application (the dist folder and reports) to another computer, the application works but the reports no longer open. Please help me with a guide in this regard, so I can open the reports. Thank you

Comment: Do you get any Exception ?

Answer (score 0):

A recent JDK must be installed. I installed JDK 17.0.1 on remote computers